# what is the difference between "for" and "at" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

in the sentece:

"Community Rules means written rules and regulations that govern the conduct of tenants for and at the Community."

it might be about technical English but I see some grammar point. If regulations that governs tenants are for Community it is automatically within Community, meaning "at" right??

I don't see the point of saying "for" and "at"

Comment: I think at the community implies "the area where it is in force."(Not in any other area)

Comment: No, it's BS.  "in the Community" would have been better English.

Answer (score 0):

It merely means that the rules are "for the community" (they benefit the people living at the community) and are enforced "at the community" (the rules can't tell you how to behave when you are not on community premises).

"Community" here refers to mobile home communities, and may refer to the physical land or the people living on the land according to context.

Answer (score 0):

> ... the conduct of tenants for and at the community.

Even though **community** only appears once, it's used to represent two different things.

1. "for the community" - **community** basically represents the tenants who collectively create a community of residents.
2. "at the community" - **community** represents the physical land and mobile homes that create the mobile home park.

It's an interesting construct because you're using two prepositions to have a noun take two different meanings even though it actually only appears once in the sentence.